# Single-source shortest path in a graph with positive weights and diameter D

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

In a problem, I am given a graph G with only **positive weights** and its **diameter** (i.e. the greatest of the shortest paths among each pairs of vertices in G) = D. The problem asks for a **single-source shortest path algorithm** that is faster than Dijkstra and runs in **O(V+E+D)** time.

*What I've considered so far:*
I have thought about the method of adding dummy nodes so as to transform G into an unweighted graph G' and then run BFS, but this would result in a complexity of: O(V+WE)

(As in G', E' = O(WE) and V = O(WE+V))

It seems to me D doesn't really help reduce the complexity of the problem at all, as the sum of weights (i.e. total number of dummy nodes to add) is irrelevant to D.

Comment: Are the edge weights required to be integral?

Comment: @MarkSaving Yes, the edge weights are positive integers

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/136565/755

Answer (score 1):

Use Djikstra's algorithm with an optimised version of the priority queue. Assume the graph has nodes `0..V-1`.

The priority queue will consist of an array `Arr[0..D]` (an array with indices between 0 and `D` inclusive) of doubly-linked lists of nodes, together with an index `i` indicating that the priority of all nodes in the array are of distance at least `i` from the starting node, and an array `location[0..V - 1]`, where the value of `location[node]` is the doubly-linked list node in `Arr` containing `node`, or `null` if there is no such node. We store a node in the list `Arr[i]` when we have found a path of length `i` from the start node to the node in question.

Adding a node to the priority queue which is not already there is `O(1)` - if we have a tentative distance `s`, then we add the node to the linked list `Arr[s]` and update `location[node]` accordingly. Note that if the priority is `>D`, we should actually refrain from adding the node to the priority queue entirely and be confident that we will later add it to the queue with a priority `<= D`.

Removing a given node from the priority queue is also `O(1)` - we can find its doubly-linked-list node in `O(1)` using `location[node]`, delete that node from the doubly-linked-list, and set `location[node]` to `null`. We will need this operation when we change the priority of a node.

Finding and removing the minimal node is less trivial. We continually increment `i` until we find some `i` such that `Arr[i]` is not empty. We then remove a node which is found in `Arr[i]` from the priority queue (don't forget to update `location[node]` as well). The total number of incrementings done in the whole program is `D`, since we will change `i` from `0` to `D` one increment at a time. Ignoring the incrementings, the other work done in this process is `O(1)`.

Note that this is ONLY valid because we can guarantee that once we remove a node with priority `i`, we will never add another node with priority `<i` into the priority queue. It also only works because we know that we could never actually remove anything added to the priority queue with priority `> D`, since we can only remove something from the priority queue when it has its finalised correct path length, which is `<= D` - therefore, it's unnecessary to add anything to the priority queue with priority `> D`. This follows from the general properties of Dijkstra's algorithm when the graph has positive edge weights, and from the fact that the graph's diameter is `D`.

So the algorithm will be `O(V + E + D)`, as required.